# WebHDFS Java client not handling Kerberos Tokens correctly

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I'm trying to run a long-lived WebHDFS client (actually building the Framework in front on HDFS). But my tokens are expiring after one day (default kerberos configuration here), at first I tried running a thread which would call

```
userLoginInformation.currentUser().checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab();
```

However even though I see the TGT relogin 21hours, but after 24h my WebHDFS Filesystem is stuck on "token not found in the cache" (which is an error meaning that the server already deleted my token).

Watching inside the code @ https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/web/WebHdfsFileSystem.java

I found the method "replaceExpiredDelegationToken". But after looking at "runWithRetry" it will be called only if "OPGETDELEGATIONTOKEN" fails (because at all other operations getRequireAuth is FALSE), which basically forces my client to run getDelegationToken at least once each day, so my token gets renewed.

**For now I'll be checking if the FS is a WebHDFS Service and then, each hour I'll do:

```
if (hdfsFileSystem instanceof WebHdfsFileSystem)
{
  WebHdfsFileSystem tmpFS = (WebHdfsFileSystem) hdfsFileSystem;
  tmpFS.setDelegationToken(tmpFS.getDelegationToken(null));
}
```

1. **Is there a better way to force delegation token renewal? (or to have long-lived clients)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days testing (so kerberos ticket would run off)

Calling

```
if (hdfsFileSystem instanceof WebHdfsFileSystem)
{
  WebHdfsFileSystem tmpFS = (WebHdfsFileSystem) hdfsFileSystem;
  tmpFS.setDelegationToken(tmpFS.getDelegationToken(null));
}
```

once each hour, it seems to work fine, IMO this should be done at HDFS level but well... it will be @ framework level for us :)